# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity, uable to acces the UI elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

As I am trying to access the UI element in my activity it's not opening and throws a runtime exception and the app crashes. I rebuilt the entire project again but the issue is same.

--XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BMIActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bmi_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

  
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llUnitsView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_bmi_activity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilMetricUnitWeight"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/etMetricUnitWeight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="WEIGHT (in kg)"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilMetricUnitHeight"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/etMetricUnitHeight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="HEIGHT (in cm)"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llDiplayBMIResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvYourBMI"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="YOUR BMI"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBMIValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="15.00" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBMIType"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:text="Normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBMIDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:text="Normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCalculateUnits"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="CALCULATE"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
 
</RelativeLayout>
```

--The error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.a7minuteworkout, PID: 4810
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a7minuteworkout/com.example.a7minuteworkout.BMIActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.a7minuteworkout:layout/activity_bmiactivity: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.a7minuteworkout:layout/activity_bmiactivity: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2239)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.a7minuteworkout:layout/activity_bmiactivity: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.a7minuteworkout:layout/activity_bmiactivity: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in com.example.a7minuteworkout:layout/activity_bmiactivity: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:855)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1012)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:963)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1142)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1103)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1145)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1103)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.a7minuteworkout.BMIActivity.onCreate(BMIActivity.kt:9)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3505)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2239)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:115)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:469)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:428)
            ... 30 more
```

can able to find that where Is issue is pointing, gone through a lot of answers but still can't find the desired result.
please anyone help Me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Logcat has the answer. It says

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

Use `Theme.MaterialComponents` theme instead `Theme.AppCompat`

Changing to Theme.MaterialComponents will have many changes in app UI, colors, sizing etc. And they will be good. Don't worry.

If you don't want to change the Theme on the entire app, try adding this to the Relative layout. (Not recommended)

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
```

Your relative layout should be:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
    tools:context=".BMIActivity">
```

Comment: How can I detect errors in my code any tips?

Comment: If it is a run-time exception, you will find the error in Logcat. Pay attention to the lines "Caused by:" and "java.lang.RuntimeException" to understand the error. If it is a compile-time exception, your IDE most probably highlights the error with a red line.